# Generating PDF reports in Node.js/express web application

Tags: node.js, express

I need to convert an existing ASP.NET MVC web application to Node.JS.
This existing .net application has an option to generate PDF reports , and to design and generate reports it use Active Reports for .NET.

I would like to know what are the options to design and generate PDF reports in case of Node.js/ Express web application.

Comment: jspdf is an option. https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many libraries that convert html to PDF. One of them is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). You can use their example of [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) to create PDFs.

The tricky part is to get it to work with NodeJS. NodeJs runs in a different process than PhantomJs. One solution could be [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/). You could do something like this [example](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/blob/master/examples/render.js):

```
const phantom = require('phantom');

(async function() {
    const instance = await phantom.create();
    const page = await instance.createPage();

    await page.property('viewportSize', {width: 1024, height: 600});
    const status = await page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/');
    console.log(`Page opened with status [${status}].`);

    await page.render('stackoverflow.pdf');
    console.log(`File created at [./stackoverflow.pdf]`);

    await instance.exit();
}());

// node --harmony-async-await render.js
```

Note you would need Node 7 to use the example above.

Disclaimer: I am the author of phantomjs-node.